# An algorithm to compute 'bridginess' of a node in an undirected graph

Tags: graphs

I have an undirected graph which may or may not contain a 'bridge'. I'm defining a bridge as a relatively narrow connection between two larger clusters. Take for example the following graph:

```
A----B
 \  /
  \/
  C
  |
  D
  |
  E
  /\
 /  \
F----G
```

In this example D would be considered the 'bridgiest' node, because it connects the two clusters ABC and EFG.

I can think of one way to do this: namely to find the shortest path from every node to every other node and keep an internal counter for every node each time it is traversed, but this is obviously pretty unrealistic for anything but very trivial graphs.

I wasn't sure how to research this, so if you have information on related problems that could also be helpful!

Comment: Do you have a clear definition of the "bridginess" of a note?  Perhaps [effective resistance](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~shayan/courses/cse599/adv-approx-4.pdf) or other notions from random walk theory can help to come up with such a definition.

Comment: I unfortunately don't. In relation to my problem, it would be most useful if the value of 'bridginess' ranged between 0 and 1, where 1 is described by the scenario where one node connects two infinitely large clusters and 0 is the case of a single point (you can't get much less bridgy than there not even being another node to connect to)

Comment: After a very short look at the link you sent, this problem could be phrased in terms of current as well - i.e. the amount of current running through a node if all nodes in one cluster have positive charge and all nodes in the other cluster have negative charge